# Implementation of Distance Vector not finding new paths

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the distance vector routing protocol from a text file, and have hit a roadblock, in that my algorithm is not finding new connections between nodes.  My node structure is

```
public class Node {

    int name;

    public int[][] connections, via;


    Node(int iName, int size) {
        name = iName;
        connections = new int[size][size];
        via = new int[size][size];
    }

}
```

and my search algorithm is

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<size; j++){

        if(node.connections[i][j]!=MAX){

            for(int k = 0; k < size; k++){
                if((node.connections[i][j]+node.connections[j][k])<node.connections[i][k]&&(node.connections[i][j]+node.connections[j][k])>0){
                     node.connections[i][k] = node.connections[i][j] + node.connections[j][k];
                     node.via[i][k] = j;
                     node.via[k][i] = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I play around with the parameters, I can get it to track connections between nodes, but only those that have initially defined connections.

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) about the Floyd-Warshall algorithm. The order should be like this pseudocode from the website:

```
for k from 1 to |V|
    for i from 1 to |V|
      for j from 1 to |V|
         if dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] < dist[i][j] then
         dist[i][j] ← dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]
```

**EDIT:**
Based on the above pseudocode, the code should look like this:

```
for(int k = 0; k < size; i++){
    for(int i = 0; j<size; j++){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            if((node.connections[i][k]+node.connections[k][j])<node.connections[i][j]
                &&(node.connections[i][k]+node.connections[k][j])>0){
                node.connections[i][j] = node.connections[i][k] + node.connections[k][j];
                node.via[i][j] = k;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The order of the loops matters because the body of the loop will behave differently. The first step is to choose the **size of the path** (k + 1 is the size of the path that we are optimizing, starting with a path of size 1). The second step is to choose a start node. The third step is to choose an end node. Then, the algorithm finds the shortest path of size 1 from the start node to another node. The second loop goes through all of the start nodes to find all of the best paths of size 1. Afterwards, the size is increased to find all the best paths of size 2, building from the best paths of size 1. This goes on until even the paths that use all of the nodes in the graph are considered.

Comment: Looking at this, it appears to be what I already have, but when it executes, it only finds the original connections, not any new paths.

Comment: Swapping the code out has gotten me one step closer, in that the via matrix is now being properly populated, but it's still only finding the initial iteration.  EDIT:  Actually it still isn't triggering the if statement.  That seems to be the problem, my if statement is always false.

Comment: @isaach1000, you are not correct about the meaning of k - k is the midpoint of the new path it tries to find to see if it's shorter. The wikipedia page you linked to explains it.

Comment: @Patashu, k both refers to the size and the midpoint. If you look at this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Example) from the same wiki page, you will see that k clearly represents the maximum size.

Comment: @CarlDavis, at first I was in agreement with Patashu, but after realizing the other interpretation of the algorithm, namely that k represents distance, I removed the if statement. Also, I have not seen that if statement in any of the implementations of the the algorithm.

Comment: Even with the max statement removed, something is wrong with the other if statement, that is making it always return false.  If the equality is switched, it becomes true, but the values returned are wrong.

Comment: You might want to remove the `&& (node.connections[i][k]+node.connections[k][j])>0`. How does the MAX value work? That could affect the comparison.

Comment: I've been using -1 or 9999 for the max value.  The max value is currently assigned to the values in the matrix that cannot have connections, specifically A->A and so on, and 0 is used to indicate there is no connection.  Removing the >0 resulted in all the non max values becoming zero.  Removing the max values didn't change anything either.

Comment: The value for A->A should be zero from the start, not MAX. The other connections should be **initialized to the weights of the edges.** From what I can tell, the connections are all initialized to zero, but the code does not show anything else.

Comment: It reads in a matrix for each node, in the format
    0 0 0 0
    0 23 0 0
    0 0 2 0
    0 0 0 0

Those are the only weights that end up stored, I am unsure what I need to change to get them storing properly.  That's supposed to be a 4X4 matrix, but the formatting won't let me.

Comment: So the way that the Floyd-Warshall algorithm works is that there is only one matrix, not one for each node. Try making the `connections` matrix separate from the nodes, so that you no longer write `node.connections` to refer to it.